# Custom value for modified field

Tags: cakephp

Can I define custom value for table modified field in CakePHP?

Something like that:

```
$data = array('modified' => date('2013-09-09 22:01:14'));
$this->Model->save($data, false);
```

Comment: I found one way for solving problem. Using [query](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#model-query) function.

Answer (score 3):

If you carefully read what the [cookbook says](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#using-created-and-modified)

> CakePHP will [..] populate them automatically whenever a record is created or saved to the database (**unless the data being saved already contains a value for these fields**).
>
> ...
>
> **If you have created or modified data in your $this->data (e.g. from a Model::read or Model::set) before a Model::save() then the values will be taken from $this->data and not automagically updated.**

So all you need to do is

```
$data = array(
    'Model' => array(
        'modified' => date('2013-09-09 22:01:14')
    )
);
```

Using `query()` should be the last resort if everything else fails.